# How to add information from another model to admin edit page

Tags: django, django-admin

I have 2 models. 
First model contains user field and file field (address to file). It can be only one file for one user.
Second model is just the same, but it is some sort of archived files. So, it can be lot's of files for one user.

I want to add for admin edit first model page list of links for archived files from the second model for the same user.
How I can do that? What is the best way? Should I redefine admin model template and view?

Example:

User - Name

File - link to file  <<<<<<<<<< I have it out of the box of django admin edit page

Archived files: <<<<<<<<< I want to add list of links to archived files

link to file1

link to file2

...

link to file N

**UPD:**
My models look like this:

```
class UserFile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    file = PrivateImageField(...)

class ArchivedUserFile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    file = PrivateImageField(...)
```

Comment: When I do so it sad, that my second model (archive) has no ForeignKey to first model.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds to me like you want to use Django's inline admins.  Tabular inline is pretty easy to use and feature complete.

So for this code:

```
from django.db import models

class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Book(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

You can register these admins for managing Authors, and the books they created:

```
from django.contrib import admin

class BookInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Book

class AuthorAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [
        BookInline,
    ]
```

Don't forget to register your admin

```
from django.contrib import admin
admin.site.register(Author, AuthorAdmin)
```

I got all of this from

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects

**OR**

If you just want to manage it yourself, you can edit the template. Don't
forget to put your iterator/QuerySet into the context so you can get to it.

See the docs on that.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-admin-templates
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/contrib/admin/#custom-template-options

and override the change_view method on your admin.ModelAdmin:

```
def change_view(self, request, object_id, form_url='', extra_content=None):
    // Set up vars
    context = {'things': list_of_things}

    return super(AuthorAdmin, self).change_view(request, object_id, form_url, context)
```

Comment: I want use inline method, but I can't. In your example you have ForeignKey link between two models, and my models looks like this:

    class UserFile(models.Model):
        user = models.ForeignKey(User)
        file = PrivateImageField(...)

    class ArchivedUserFiles(models.Model):
        user = models.ForeignKey(User)
        file = PrivateImageField(...)

Will try second method soon...

Answer (score 0):

There's no reason you can't use inlines here. The main stumbling block will be that the User model is automatically registered in the admin. Make your ModelAdmins as so:

```
...
from django.contrib.auth import User
...


class UserFileInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = UserFile


class ArchivedUserFileInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = ArchivedUserFile


class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = (
        UserFileInline,
        ArchivedUserFileInline,
    )


# Unregister User from the admin and re-register with our ModelAdmin
admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

Now you can play with your files from the User admin.

Comment: How would you mix inlines from different app to the same Model. For example User Model may have many relations in other apps and they all need to add inlines?